# Jupyter Notebook can't find module

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, twython

Hi I have been trying to install twython for Jupyter Notebook. I have proved through the python repl that it is universally installed throughout  my laptop. But it still won't appear on Jupyter Notebook. Looking for help trying to figure out it is found in a spot that it can be found by my Anaconda 3 Jupyter Notebook.

Context: Homework assignment trying to mine twitter for tweets

Here is the errors I am receiving and I am running Mac OS

```
/Users/name/twitter/__init__.py:22: UserWarning: The twython library has not been installed. Some functionality from the twitter package will not be available.
  "The twython library has not been installed. "
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-38297a1141e0> in <module>
----> 1 import twitter
      2 import twython
      3 #---------------------------------------------
      4 # Define a Function to Login Twitter API
      5 def oauth_login():

~/twitter/__init__.py in <module>
     34 
     35 
---> 36 from nltk.twitter.common import json2csv

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk.twitter
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed nltk package?

If not, do it:

1. `pip3 install -U nltk`
2. then run `python3`
3. inside python3 command line, run:

   `import nltk
   nltk.download()`
4. after the download, restart jupyter, and run your code again.